# Image slider in tensorboard automatically goes to end while user scrolls through images

Tags: image, pytorch, tensorboard

I am using TensorBoard 2.2.0 to visualize my input image to a neural network in PyTorch. After running the code and I try to go through the recorded image data. However, when I try to browse it the image slider automatically jumps from the current step to the last step after some time. Any reason why this could be happening.

I am launching the tensorboard using this command -

```
tensorboard --logdir runs --samples_per_plugin images=0
```

Answer (score 0):

I fell through a similar dilemma. You could turn off the `relead after 30s` option from settings in the tensorboard. [GitHub issue on the same](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorboard/issues/1681)